# How to change filetype of all files within a directory in bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory called letters an a bash script at the same level. What I want to do is change all docx files to txt. As a first step I tried to use the find command to list every docx file. My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

letters_dir="$(cd "$(dirname "./letters")"; pwd)/$(basename "./letters")"

$files_docx=$(find $letters_dir -type f -iname "*.docx")

for $file in $files_docx; do
    echo $file
done
```

The error I'm getting is

> ./05.sh: line 5: =/media/gdisk/Documents: The file or directory does not exist
> ./05.sh: line 9: `$file': is not a valid identifier

I also tried passing the relative directory to the find command. Like this:

```
$files_docx=$(find letters -type f -iname "*.docx")
```

But I get the same result

Comment: Why `$files_docx=` ? Isn't `files_docx=` correct?

Comment: Use `$` when *getting* the value of a variable, but never when *setting* it. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting mistakes like this. Also, that's not a valid way to find the "letters" directory: `dirname "./letters"` just prints ".", `cd .` does nothing, and so `pwd` will give you the working directory inherited from whatever ran the script (which might or might not be anywhere near the script itself). See [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Comment: @Gordon's explanation is excellent (as usual). One more note for @Dexter... keep it simple. `for file in letters/*.docx; do mv $file ${file%.docx}.txt; done`

Answer (score 1):

Using command `rename` on ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt install rename

rename 's/\.docx$/\.txt/' *.docx
```